# Find Instagram User by ID

Tags: jquery, instagram, instagram-api

I am working on a third party tool and let's say i have bunch of user ID. Is there any way to retrive user basic (pubic) user information only by ID? i have tried blockspring's get instagram user info tool via jQuery and used this code:

```
blockspring.runParsed("get-instagram-user-info", { "user": "x", "using_id": false}, { "api_key": "br_***_***" }, function(res){
console.log(res.params);
```

})

where i placed the x i have tried sending user id as both string and int, with and without quotes, i've also tried as "using_id": true but no luck. all i see is Object{} definition at console. solution doesnt have to be blockspring. all solutions accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gramfeed to retrieve a bunch of user profile info and download as csv:

http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/user

login via instagram and enter a bunch of user ids separated by comma or space and retrieve.

[image]